# What if call_user_func is supposed to return false?

Tags: php

The function I'm calling with `call_user_func` is supposed to return FALSE.  So how do I detect errors if the callable is invalid?

(Side note: Why didn't they have this throw an exception rather than return an error code?  Or is there a way to "catch" errors?  I have an error handle.  Should I have it throw exceptions for me?)

Comment: Also, I swear I tried to search this and just couldn't find the magic words to get me there.  Directing me to an appropriate question would be great if you know it.

Comment: You could test with [`is_callable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) first.

Comment: "Invalid" meaning the function doesn't exist, for example.  The error handle gets something like: "Error #2: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'SomeClass' does not have a method 'asdfasdfasdf'"

Comment: `is_callable` just might do the trick in my case. Still, I would like someone to explain the language design decision there....

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think Exceptions were introduced in PHP5. Most functions available before that (such as `call_user_func`) raise errors instead of throwing exceptions. There is a way to circumvent that, though. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: @bfavaretto - You should post that as an answer.  It's a very reasonable solution in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to check if the function or method to be called really exists, you can use [`is_callable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) before calling [`call_user_func`](http://se.php.net/call_user_func). You may wrap the whole thing in a function for easy reuse:

```
function call_uf($fn) {
    if(is_callable($fn)) {
        return call_user_func($fn);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("$fn is not callable");
    }
}
```

You asked in a comment about why PHP raises errors instead of using exceptions. I think that's because exceptions were introduced only in PHP5, so most PHP functions rely on error reporting. There seems to be a way around that, as [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) indicates:

> Internal PHP functions mainly use [Error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting), only modern [Object oriented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) extensions use exceptions. However, errors can be simply translated to exceptions with [ErrorException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php).

Comment: In my opinion, sometimes backwards compatibility just needs to go.  However, I am so digging that `ErrorException` business.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They did not throw Exception because they need keep this function backward compatible.
There was no Exception in older PHP versions, PHP < 5.

The boolean return type was "reserved" for function failure report.
What you need to do is discover why the function would fail.
I guess the only reason it would fail is for invalid arguments.

Maybe wraping it in a safe call would do what you want:

```
function safe_call_user_func()
{
  $nargs = func_num_args();
  $args = func_get_args();
  if ( $nargs == 0 )
    throw new RuntimeException( 'Require at least the callback param' );
  if ( !is_callable( $args[0] )
    throw new InvalidArgumentException( 'Callback param is invalid' );
  return call_user_func_array( array_shift( $args ), $args );
}
```