# Check if call_user_func_array was executed succesfully

Tags: php, call-user-func-array

A function or method can be called dynamically using `call_user_func_array`. If the call itself fails, `FALSE` is returned. Also, `call_user_func_array` returns the return values from the function or method that is called.

So when the called function or method returns `FALSE` as well (for example, see SO [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068748/php-calling-function-dynamically-returns-null)), that value would be recognised as a false positive.

How can one reliably check if the function or method call was executed succesfully by `call_user_func_array`?

**EDIT**: People tend to point out the existence of `is_callable`. But this is not about checking if a method exists before calling it, thus avoiding possible errors. Actually before doing `call_user_func_array` the function call and it's arguments and argument types are already verified using `Reflection` to avoid a [Massive Assign attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Mass_Assignment_Cheat_Sheet).

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) mentions the `FALSE` return value, but I fail to see how it can be used to check if the call was succesful.

Comment: Look at this [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php#109357)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767728/what-if-call-user-func-is-supposed-to-return-false

Comment: Instead of having the callable return a bool, why not make it void and let it throw an exception on error and catch that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd transform the boolean callable into one that is void but that throws an exception on error.

That way, you could catch the exception and you would know if `false` was returned by the `call_user_func_array` that only its call failed:

```
<?php
$booleanCallable = function (... $args): bool {
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        echo "$arg \n";
    };

    return false;
};

$transformBooleanCallableToVoidThrowingException = function (callable $c): callable {
    return function (... $args) use ($c): void {
        if (false === $c(... $args)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("the call to the callable failed");
        }
    };
};

try {
    $callable = $transformBooleanCallableToVoidThrowingException($booleanCallable);
    $response = call_user_func_array($callable, [1, 2, 3]);

    if (false === $response) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("call_user_func_array failed");
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This will output the provided arguments and an error message:

```
1 
2 
3 
the call to the callable failed
```

Comment: That being said, I would avoid php functions like `call_user_func` and `call_user_func_array` unless it is *really* necessary. Most of time, you know which function should be called.

Answer (score 5):

You can explicitly check whether an error occurred during the last call:

```
error_clear_last();  // since PHP 7, before that you'll need to store and
                     // compare the error state before and after the call

$result = call_user_func_array($foo, $bar);

if ($result === false && error_get_last()) {
    echo 'Failed to call ', $foo;
}
```

The above is a generic check for *any* error, perhaps you want to inspect the last error in more detail. It'll look something like:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'foo' not found or invalid function name
    [file] => /in/M8PrG
    [line] => 3
)
```

You might want to check that the `message` matches something like `'call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback'` and/or that the line it refers to is the line above. Note that especially checking the message may break between PHP versions.

---

The alternative is to check *before* whether your supposed callback [`is_callable`](http://php.net/is_callable).

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted, I would think checking the last error is a more complete solution than just checking if it is callable as arguments might be missing for example.

Comment: Quite honestly I would like to downvote PHP for necessitating this bending-over backwards; sane use of exceptions would solve this much more elegantly… ;)

Comment: Just look at the bright side, PHP offers **both** exception handling and error reporting. Consider it a convenience, just like `declare(strict_types=1);`. And while we're waiting, maybe someday we have a `declare` statement to allow multiple inheritance as well, even when it is [not really needed](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#multiple).

Comment: @deceze Then implement using exceptions. There's too many different scenarios where one could use call_user_func_array() to try so solve this with one specific pattern. I upvote PHP for allowing different routes to handling errors with this function.